Deep Learning _ Keep getting Channel Error mismatch for my U-Net Model

As i try to run my y prediction to my model of x batch , it shows me a mismatch.
This is the error I get:
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [512, 1024, 3, 3], expected input[16, 1536, 16, 16] to have 1024 channels, but got 1536 channels instead.

This is my model definition:
class UNet(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.pool1 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)

      self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv4 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.pool2 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)

      self.conv5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv6 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.pool3 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2, stride = 2)

      self.conv7 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv8 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.pool4 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride = 2)

      self.conv9 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv10 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1024, 1024, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.Upsample = torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)

      self.conv11 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv12 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv13 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.Upsample = torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)

      self.conv14 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv15 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.Upsample = torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)

      self.conv16 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv17 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.Upsample = torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)

      self.conv18 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv19 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv20 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
      self.conv21 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 1, kernel_size=1, padding='same')
      self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x1 = self.relu(x) # We'll use this result later!
    x = self.pool1(x1)

    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv4(x)
    x2 = self.relu(x)
    x = self.pool2(x)

    x = self.conv5(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv6(x)
    x3 = self.relu(x)
    x = self.pool3(x)

    x = self.conv7(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv8(x)
    x4 = self.relu(x)
    x = self.pool4(x)

    x = self.conv9(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv10(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.Upsample(x)

    x = torch.cat((x, x4), dim=1)

    x = self.conv11(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv12(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv13(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.Upsample(x)

    x = torch.cat((x, x3), dim=1)
                  
    x = self.conv14(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv15(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.Upsample(x)

    x = torch.cat((x, x2), dim=1)
      
    x = self.conv16(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv17(x)

    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv18(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.Upsample(x)

    x = torch.cat((x, x1), dim=1)
        
    x = self.conv19(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv20(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv21(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    #x = self.sigmoid(x)

    return x

I'm wondering if some of my layers were wrong. i'm trying to match it exactly to the diagram but Maybe i've added an extra layer , or incorrect channel order . I've made sure to concatenate as well (4 grey arrows in picture).

You are calculating the wrong number of channels for your conv11 layer.
After the first upsampling operation, you are concatenating the upsampled tensor x which has 1024 channels with x4 which has 512 channels. do the math and you'll end up with 1024+512=1536. so you should change your conv11 to
self.conv11 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1536, 512, kernel_size=3, padding='same')

This is the case for the other concatenations as well, so you also need to change these layers:
self.conv12 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
self.conv14 = torch.nn.Conv2d(768, 256, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
self.conv16 = torch.nn.Conv2d(384, 128, kernel_size=3, padding='same')
self.conv19 = torch.nn.Conv2d(192, 64, kernel_size=3, padding='same')


If you check your diagram again, you should see that the up arrow mean an UpConv (which could either be a TransposedConv or a Conv+Upsample (Upsample+Conv)), which definitely change the channels of the features, while you only use an Upsample layer, which is not changing the output channels. You should change the Upsample layer to:
self.Upsample = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv(in_channels,in_channels//2, 1,1,0),
                              nn.Upsample(2))

where the in_channels should come from the output of the previous conv layer of your net.
